# How to make images move into available whitespace

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm creating a picture gallery page, but I'm running into issues with the images not moving into available whitespace. Heres an example:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
div {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
img {
  float: left;
}
.lscape {
  width: 33%;
}
.port {
  width: 33%;
}
```

```html
<div>

  <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/c7oV1T2j5mc/maxresdefault.jpg" class="lscape">
  <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/c7oV1T2j5mc/maxresdefault.jpg" class="lscape">
  <img src="http://www.cat-portraits.com/Images/cat_portrait_painting_in_pastels.jpg" class="port">
  <img src="http://www.cat-portraits.com/Images/cat_portrait_painting_in_pastels.jpg" class="port">
  <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/c7oV1T2j5mc/maxresdefault.jpg" class="lscape">
  <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/c7oV1T2j5mc/maxresdefault.jpg" class="lscape">

</div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What are your expectations? What are you trying to achieve? From what I can see everything is behaving as I would expect it to.

Comment: @hungerstar I assume he wants it to vertically align to the top.

Comment: Ideally I was hoping to get the images to move up into the white space above

Comment: It is not taking the free space in the first row as the images are block elements.  I think you are looking for masonry styled formatting for your images. This can be achieved by CSS column properties. The following article gets a detailed write up how you can get your desired output, but it requires lot more work on the code [Creating a CSS-only Responsive Masonry](http://w3bits.com/css-masonry/)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two great sources to solve this problem:

1.[Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) - a JavaScript grid layout library. This will help with the layout.

2.[Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/filtering.html) - which is from the same author but you can also add filtering options.

Hope that these solve your problem!

Answer (score 0):

Try "[Masonry](http://masonry.desandro)" - a JavaScript grid layout library by Dave DeSandro. It works like charm [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/).